# $filter not getting the desired output in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have JSON field like below,

```
"newId":5
```

i have my search object like,

```
{aId: "5", aName: "Other"}
```

and have written filter like,

```
$filter('filter')($scope.races, {newId:myObj.aId},true);
```

I get an empty array as output. I tried adding toString() also did not work. Am i doing anything wrong.

Comment: it worked when i make aId as integer ({aId: 5, aName: "Other"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution:
1- To make both fields of the same data type :

```
$scope.races = [{"newId":5}]
var myObje = {aId: 5, aName: "Other"};
$filter('filter')($scope.races, {newId:myObje.aId},true);
```

Note: aId = 5 (not "5").

2- to write your custom comparator

```
$filter('filter')($scope.races, {newId:myObje.aId},function(a,b){return a == b;});
```

Note: a==b (not a === b).

Comment: But i see in documentation that Primitive values are converted to strings. So if i do toString() its should work na. but it also does not.

Comment: Could you surround newId by " like s, {"newId":myObje.aId},

Answer (score 0):

filter expects that the `$scope.races` must be an array, so your response from JSON must be added to an array and in this case your code will work

```
var myObj = {aId: "5", aName: "Other"};
$scope.races = [{newId: 5}]
var result = $filter('filter')($scope.races, {newId: myObj.aId}, true);
```

Comment: @ Aleksandar Gajic - yes its same structure. But it does not work

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cajg4yxz/1/ and you can see it is working in this example

Comment: because aId and newId are not of the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

I make a solution for you and I think it's work fine. The problem is in your filter:

```
$scope.result = $filter('filter')($scope.races, {
    newId: +$scope.myObj.aId //parse $scope.myObj.aId to int
}, true);
```

[Solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/JEk8jiGkIelkHSzQ6iCc?p=preview)